# django local static file configuration

Tags: django

Somehow in a Django project, I changed my config for static files. Now I have to run `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` before I run `python manage.py runserver`. Otherwise whatever changes I made to my project will not show up. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: use incognito mode

Comment: incognito mode has the same problem. I have to run manage.py collectstatic --noinput
Otherwise, the changes will not show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is to update statics from the server:

```
ctrl + F5 in your Browser
```

=> If you can see your changes, it's fine.

=> if not: take look at your settings: you have two seperates statics folders:

*the one you modify

*a second one that you display, it should be @ STATIC_ROOT

When you run collectstatic, you just copy the first folder to the STATIC_ROOT

Please if you need more help, share your settings.py file